# How to read a JS file as plain text and put it as string into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a test.js file and I want to get the code of that file and put it into a variable as string, but without execute it How can I do this ?

I can use this jquery code

```
$j.get('/js/apu.js', function(data) {
    $j('#result').html(data);
});
```

But the problem with this is that execute the JS code, I dont want execute it, I just want to place the code into a variable (of course to manipulate it after as string/plain text)

UPDATE:

Just the fact of $j.get('/js/apu.js'... executes the code without print it in the page. I don't what that behavior, I only need to get the code as plain text.

Comment: if you want to put the code into a variable, why are you not, you know, putting it in a variable and instead putting it on the page?

Comment: Because I also want to print it as plain text, but when I do it then the JS code is executed as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
$("#container").load("/js/apu.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the question's title, `data` itself is a string variable that contains the code as plain text.

The Javascript is not executed unless enclosed within `<script></script>` tags. But html entities may need escaping if you don't want the browser to interpret it as html.
I don't understand what kind of manipulation you are planning, but if you just want to print it as plain text within your page, use `.text()` instead of `.html()` :

```
$j('#result').text(data);
```

*I would also suggest to make result as a `<pre>` or `<code>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `dataType` to text.

```
$j.get('/js/apu.js', function(data) {
    $j('#result').html(data);
}, "text");
```